# Spring MVC + hibernate batch loading from db

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Sorry guys if it is a trivial question, but I want to figure out the right way. There is a large table 'account' (about 10000 entries). I want to iterate through it do some logic with entity and merge it back if needed. But I don't want to load all entries in memory.

Currently I do this

```
List<Account> accounts = accountsDAO.all();
for (Account a: accounts) {
  doSomeCode(a);
  accountsDAO.merge(a);
}
```

How can I improve it?

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.3. Is it important?

Comment: What problem you have in memory with these 10000 records ? Does it take too much time or memory ? It does not sounds too heavy. If its a child of some other parent entity you could  load it lazily.

Comment: Alright, what if there would be 1M entries?

Comment: In fact we have used Hibernate to deal with 40 M records. But we don't load 40 M at once, its all lazy loaded when needed. Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827081/loading-million-rows-in-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`setFirstResult`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) and [`setMaxResults`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) to do it rather manually and with quite explicit queries (think SQL's `LIMIT` clause).

There is also [`setFetchSize`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFetchSize%28int%29) to let the driver/database chunk the results of an unlimited query ([example in the PostgreSQL JDBC docs](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html)). [`ScrollableResults`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/ScrollableResults.html) seems to be quite similar (regarding the usage at least): you are getting a result iterator to scroll over the matched records ([example in a random blog post](http://koenserneels.blogspot.de/2013/03/bulk-fetching-with-hibernate.html)).

As to my question which database you are using: There are differences between the databases and/or drivers. I do not know specifics here, but some features regarding loading in chunks must be supported by the respective DB driver.