# OUT OF MEMORY in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I have created many to one relationship in hibernate.
Following is the code for that.

there are thousands of records present in B table which is link to single record of table A.  When i used getBList() method it will returns thousands of record and JAVA goes OUT OF MEMORY.
So how can i solve this problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    private int Id;
    private String aName;
    private List<MksReleaseInfo> bList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return releaseId;
    }

    public void setId(final int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    @Column(name = "aname", unique = true)
    public String getAName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setAName(final String aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "aName")
    public List<MksReleaseInfo> getBList() {
        return bList;
    }

    public void setBList(final List<B> bList) {
        this.bList = bList;
    }
}   


@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    private int bIndex;
    private int bpriority;
    private A aName;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected int getBIndex() {
        return mksReleaseInfoIndex;
    }

    protected void setBIndex(final int bIndex) {
        this.bIndex = bIndex;
    }

    @Column(name = "priority")
    public int getBPriority() {
        return bpriority;
    }

    public void setBPriority(final int bpriority) {
        this.bpriority = bpriority;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Id")
    public A getAName() {
        return aName;
    }

    public void setAName(final A aName) {
        this.aName = aName;
    }
}
```

after all the comments i have implemented the following code.  but again it gives OUT OF MEMORY. Should i have to flush the memory explicitly and how?

```
public List<B> getList(String name, int offset, int limit) throws DAOException {
        try {
            String hql = "from B where name = :name";
            begin();
            Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
            query.setString("name", name);

            if(offset > 0){
                query.setFirstResult(offset);
            }

            if(limit > 0){
                query.setMaxResults(limit);
                query.setFetchSize(limit);
            }
            commit();
            return query.list();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            rollback(); 
        }
    }

    public Long countB(String name) throws DAOException {
        try {
            String hql = "select count(*) from B where name = :name";
            begin();
            Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
            query.setString("name", name);
            commit();
            return (Long)query.uniqueResult();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            rollback();
        }
    }


    long count = countB(name);
    int counter = (int) (count / 200);
    if(count%200 > 0){
        counter++;
    }
    for(int j = 0;j<counter;j++){
        lists = getList(name, j*200, 200);

        for(B count1 : lists){
            System.out.println(count1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So you said what the problem is, I recommend you to change your algorithm. What do you want to do? I believe there very rare cases when you need to fetch thousands of "Many" side of the relation together.

Comment: You may test `StatelessSession` too, it can help....

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce a `DAO` in order to retrieve the records from `B` given a  `A` object in a paged way.

For example:

```
public interface BDao {

   Page findByA(A a, PageRequest pageRequest);

}
```

Maybe you could take an idea from approach taked in [Spring Data](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)

Answer (score 1):

Set `MaxResults` property of datasource, it will set limit on number of records you are getting.

Also, you can increase java heap memory size using `-Xmx256m`. This will set maximum heap allocation size to 256MB. You can set it as you need.

Comment: we can set the MaxResults property in query object.  but i m just using getBList() method.   So how i will get control over that function.  And the thing is that i want all the record from particular record in A but not immidiately, i can use it in the chunk of records but how can i do it so that there is no problem of out of memory.

Comment: good, you can do that too. But don't you think, you have set it each time when you will be executing query.

Comment: That is the reason i dont want to use query. And please read the above comment again i have edited that.  So that you can get what my question is upto.

Answer (score 1):

You can use query with paging for this purpose. In `Query` class you can find `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults` methods which can help you to iterate over records. If you need to load all B objects and store them you can adjust memory settings of java by setting `-Xmx` option. Also you can try to declare some kind of reduced class B (for example `ReducedB`), which contains only required fields, and use iterating with converting `B` to `ReducedB` to reduce memory usage.

Also you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783301/jpa-hibernate-big-collections) question. I think that it is close enought to what you want.

P.S. Final solution would depend on particular issue that you want to solve.

Comment: I have done exactly the same but again i get OUT OF MEMORY. I updated my code in my question so you can check it out.

Comment: I think that cause of `OUT OF MEMORY` is the same. Do you store all B objects at the same time? Maybe objects that you fetch from DB were not garbage collected? You can try `jvisualvm` tool to discover where memory had gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I looked at my code and server space but nothing helped. Later I looked into data and realized wrongly placed data was making application use lot of processing power. Make sure you do not have duplicated data in child class.